# Predict values in place of NA by using the original data frame?

Tags: r, predict

I have a dataset and the row which I need has an NA value.

If I use `na.omit`, the rows will be omitted; however, I need the row. Hence I need to predict a value in place of the NA.

How do I proceed?

Comment: We are missing a lot of information here, what's the technology used? Can we see some code?

Comment: I am using R code for this and have installed  ("XML") ("xml2") ("RCurl")("bitops") packages. I have pulled the data from a website and installed the package for the site as well and ran all libraries. I have just 1 NA value but removing it using na.omit will remove the entire row. I need the row. So how do i replace it